# Weaker condition for change-of-variables in Riemann integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

As I have seen in analysis books, the change-of-variables theorem for Riemann integrals gives

$$ \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(x) \,dx = \int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)\,dx$$

Conditions for $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f: g([a,b]) \to \mathbb{R}$ are usually that $f$ is continuous and $g$ is continuously differentiable.

The proof defines $F(x) = \int_{g(a)}^{g(x)} f(t)\,dt$ and since $f$ is continuous we use FTC to get $F'(x) =f(g(x))g'(x)$.   Also $F(a) = 0$ so that

$$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(x)\,dx = F(b) = F(b)-F(a) = \int_a^bF'(x)\,dx = \int_a^bf(g(x))g'(x)\,dx$$

**Question:** I also read somewhere that if  $g$ is a monotonic function we can drop the assumption that $f$ is continuous and only assume it is integrable.  How is this proved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVT makes it possible to write $$\left|\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f - \sum_{i=1}^n f(g(\xi_i)) g'(\xi_i) (x_i-x_{i-1})\right| \le $$$$ \left|\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f - \sum_{i=1}^n f(g(\xi_i))(g(x_i)-g(x_{i-1})) \right| + \left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(g(\xi_i))(g'(\eta_i)-g'(\xi_i))(x_i-x_{i-1})\right|$$ Assuming what you say in your question, it is only about to play the usual $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ game, remembering $f$ is bounded and $g$ and $g'$ are uniformly continuous.

Of course every tagged partition of $[a,b]$ induces a tagged partition of $[g(a),g(b)]$ through $g$ .

Comment: Thank you.  I could see that if $\|P\|$ is sufficiently small the second term is  $< \epsilon$ because $g'$ is uniformly continuous, but I was puzzled about the first term.  But now I see that $\sum g(\xi_i)(g(x_i)-g(x_{i-1}))$ is a Riemann sum for $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f$ since $g$ is monotonic.